# How to get 'complete' download size of a url with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to scrape some websites but I need to get the total bytes downloaded and cant seem to figure that out.

i.e I need to get the total bytes downloaded from the 'get' request including headers, body, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one look at the API would have helped:

```
Connection.Response response = ...
int size = response.bodyAsBytes().length;
```

(http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html#bodyAsBytes())

Comment: Wont that only return the size of the 'body'? i.e not the actual download size which also includes response headers,etc?

Comment: I thought you wanted to exclude headers "So calculating the size of the 'response' alone will not suffice as the response also has other stuff like headers, etc, that consume bytes."?

Comment: Nevertheless, just add the size for every header (`response.headers().entrySet()`) to the size of the body (http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Base.html#headers())